# awk command loop

Tags: awk

my filelist is like below:

```
12as.pdb
132l.pdb
135l.pdb
13pk.pdb
```

i have a command like this :

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$3;next} ($1$2 in a) {print $1,$2,a[$1$2],$3}' file1 file2
```

i want to write a loop bash that generate this command pairwise like below:

```
   awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$3;next} ($1$2 in a) {print $1,$2,a[$1$2],$3}' 12as.pdb 132l.pdb

   awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$3;next} ($1$2 in a) {print $1,$2,a[$1$2],$3}' 12as.pdb 135l.pdb

  awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$3;next} ($1$2 in a) {print $1,$2,a[$1$2],$3}' 12as.pdb  13pk.pdb
```

can anybody write that bash script and help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is **NOT** a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders *but you need to help yourself first. :-)* You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of script which you could take it as a start up and let me know how it goes then. Since you haven't let us know much information about sample Input_file(s) and outputs so based on your question here is the answer, in spite of creating awks multiple times we could create a function for it.

```
#!/bin/bash
CHECK (){
 awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$3;next} ($1$2 in a) {print $1,$2,a[$1$2],$3}' "$1"  "$2"
}

CHECK 12as.pdb 132l.pdb
CHECK 12as.pdb 135l.pdb
CHECK 12as.pdb 13pk.pdb
```

So logic is create a function put `awk` code and pass file names as arguments to it and call that function with different file names which you want to pass.

Comment: @down voter: Please do mention the reason of down vote.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I guess seeing from the edit history, it seems like you were passing C-style arguments to a bash function.

Comment: @Inian, yeah I got confuse with C and bash syntaxes but my logic was same only, then edited it as per BASH :)

Comment: thank you for your answer but i need that bash do                                  12as.pdb 132l.pdb                                                                                  12as.pdb 135l.pdb                                                                                 12as.pdb 13pk.pdb       for me

Comment: @SinaSameti, so bash is not doing it for you? :) It is processing files right without writing `awk` code again and again, if you want to do in a single awk then kindly do let us know your complete requirement on same.

Comment: with concatenation `a bc` -> `abc` and `ab c` -> `abc`. Now consider your array indices.

Answer (score 0):

since only your second file is a variable do in a bash loop

```
for f in {1321,1351,13pk}.pdb; 
do
   awk '....' 12as.pdb $f;  
done
```

also in you `awk` script change `[$1$2]` to `[$1,$2]` and `$1$2 in a` to `($1,$2) in a` unless you know what you're doing